# Sending an email via MailChimp vs "Gmail Append HTML"

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-email

I'm trying to send a responsive marketing email via Gmail using a Google Chrome plugin named "Gmail Append HTML", but when I send, the layout is still not responsive. If I use an email marketing manager, like MailChimp, it works very well, the same code goes responsive.

What does MailChimp do that Gmail can't do to send responsive marketing email? Is there a way to use Gmail instead of go outside from email website to go to another site *(like MailChimp)* just to send an email?

Here is my simple code using MJML:

```
<mjml>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-section>
      <mj-column>
        <mj-divider border-color="#F45E43"></mj-divider>
        <mj-text font-size="20px" color="#F45E43" font-family="helvetica">Hello World</mj-text>
      </mj-column>

      <mj-column>
        <mj-divider border-color="#F45E43"></mj-divider>
        <mj-text font-size="20px" color="#F45E43" font-family="helvetica">Hello World</mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

You can easily try this code and convert to HTML here: [MJML Try it Live!](https://mjml.io/try-it-live)

Comment: Is it on column or two column layout? how do you know it's not responsive? can we see some of the code? or at least were do you think the problem is.

Comment: Hi @Adam , yes, there are 2 columns. I edited my question to you see how simple test i'm doing =)